# Why is my query not returning what I expect?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

The code below is what I am trying to use in order to get the count of one column and the averages of two other columns from multiple tables and then put the results into another table.
I thought this would work, but the count that is being put into the new table is incorrect as are the averages. A lot of times the averages are outside the range of the numbers that are being averaged. The numbers that are being averaged are all negative and most of them contain decimals. The data type for the columns is set to `Number` and the field size for the numbers being averaged (the source and the destination) is set to `Double`.

---

#### Code:

```
    For i = 1000 To 1783   
    strQuery1 = "Insert Into MIUsInGridAvgs (NumberofMIUs, ProjRSSI, RealRSSI)  " & _
                "Select  Count(MIUID), Avg(ProjRSSI), Avg(RealRSSI) " & _
                "From MIUsInGrid" & i & " "
                
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False  
    DoCmd.RunSQL strQuery1  
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Next
```

The table names I am querying from all end with numbers between 1000 and 1783 inclusive.

---

#### Example Data:

`MIUsInGrid1000`

```
    MIUID       Latitude    Longitude    ProjRSSI   RealRSSI
    110108098   32.593021   -85.367073  -97.4625    -108
```

`MIUsInGrid1001`

```
    MIUID        Latitude    Longitude   ProjRSSI   RealRSSI
    110112556   32.592461   -85.337067  -101           -95
    110106208   32.592766   -85.337059  -101           -100
    110115010   32.59288    -85.337189  -101           -98
```

`MIUsInGrid1002`

```
    MIUID       Latitude    Longitude   ProjRSSI            RealRSSI
    110172260   32.593349   -85.366318  -104.408333333333   -99
    110106870   32.593464   -85.365822  -104.408333333333   -106
```

---

#### Results:

```
    NumberofMIUs    ProjRSSI           RealRSSI
    1             -97.4625             -108      'MIUsInGrid1000
    1             -100.883333333333    -109      'MIUsInGrid1001
    1             -109.521428571429    -99      'MIUsInGrid1002
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing obvious in the code you posted. Reduce your table down to a few records, post the records and the exact code including how you're displaying the values.

Comment: Also when I run it for just one table, instead of looping it, I get the correct results.

Comment: Yippee!! Rich B is back to harassing me again!! Thanks for the down-votes for no reason. Get a life and leave me alone kid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer but I don't really understand it. The column **NumberofMIUs** had the "`Indexed`" property set to "`Yes (Duplicates OK)`". When I changed the setting to "`No`" the query worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to group by something in order to be able to use the `AVG()` group function?

What value does your `i` variable contain?

Comment: I'm betting i is an index and he's expecting the value to be averaged across all the tables. :P

Comment: Nope. I only want the average for each table individually. i is being used to step through each table. And since I wanted the average for all records in each table, I didn't think I needed to use Group.

Answer (score 1):

What are the data types involved? What are the types of the columns in the `MIUsInGrid###` as well as `MIUsInGridAvgs`?

Are you sure the tables are populated as you list them with no averages or other rows?

What happens if you run the queries one at a time by hand?